# Viewshed output does not make sense

Tags: arcgis-desktop, viewshed, visibility

I am trying to perform a viewshed analysis (using the visibility function), however the output only shows a very strange area for the visibility areas. It makes no sense that my point which is at a high elevated level would be only seeing things to its east. I am not sure what is wrong and I get weird outputs with several different point I try. [image]

Comment: Can you add some more detail about the parameters you used for the input? Did you use the Viewshed or Viewshed 2 geoprocessing tool?

Comment: I used visibility, all the other settings were unchanged. I also tried ofsetting the height at 1.5 and making the radius 5000 but that is it. Everything else is normal

Comment: Ahh, sorry I missed that you had the tool listed in your question. What does the rest of the terrain look like to the south and west? That pink polygon is obscuring the area you're concerned about. I'm assuming there's nothing weird going on there with your elevation raster, but I'm curious.

Comment: I used DEM but its only for the region that I need, under that it looks all okay when I look at just the DEM.